# tweetable returns an empty div

Tags: jquery, twitter

i'm trying to display a twitter feed like how [washio](https://www.getwashio.com/) does it. they are using both [tweetable 2.1.1](https://github.com/philipbeel/Tweetable) and [timeago 1.3.1](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago), and so am i.

according to the example given in the documentation of both plugins, this should work. but it doesn't. All i get is a blank `div`. any idea what i'm missing? I'm not getting any errors on firebug either

my html

```
<div id="tweets" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

my javascript

```
<script>
/* Initalize Twitter Feed */
$('#tweets').tweetable({
     username: 'myusername',
    html5: true,
     onComplete:function($ul){
    $('time').timeago();
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#tweets').fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind solved it. since the javascript code in in my html and not an external file, i had to wrap it around a on document ready `$(function() { ... });`

like this

```
$('#tweets').tweetable({
     username: 'username',
    time: true,
      limit: 5,
      replies: false,
      loading: 'Pacience is an art...' ,
      position: 'append',
      failed: "Sorry, twitter is currently unavailable for this user.",
    html5: true,
    cacheInMilliseconds: 10,
     onComplete:function($ul){
    $('time').timeago();
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#tweets').fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
});
```